# What is the best way to merge 3 data frames without their inner intersection (Coursera Assignment 3 of data science)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, outer-join

I am trying to solve assignment 3 of `Introduction to data science on coursera`. After finishing the first question, which basically, cleaning and merging data frames, we moved to question 2.

`Question 1` was about merging 3 data frames:

1. The first df is about energy per each country (227 countries);
2. GDP table based on countries as well (264)
3. Ranking table based on countries (191 ranking, 1 rank per country)

They asked us to only merge these 3 data frames, based on county as index, and taking only the first 15 ranks, which worked fine.

The second question was about how many rows we lost when we merged 3 tables based on first 15 ranks:

> The previous question joined three datasets then reduced this to just
> the top 15 entries. When you joined the datasets, but before you
> reduced this to the top 15 items, how many entries did you lose?
>
> This function should return a single number.

[image]

What I have done to solve is to merge tables of `GDP` and `Energy` using:

```
energy_gdp = pd.merge(energy, GDP, how='inner', right_on='Country', left_on='Country')
print(len(energy_gdp))
```

Which returned 186 entries out of 264 rows from GDP and 227 from energy table.

Then I merged `energy_gdp` with the `ScimEn` but without the first 15 ranks:

```
ScimEn = ScimEn[15:]
```

And:

```
df = pd.merge(ScimEn, Energy_GDP_df, left_on='Country', right_on='Country', how='inner')
return len(df)
```

The result was `147` rows.

While searching online for solution, the result was `156`.

I did the following to make sure my answer is correct:

```
ScimEn_initial = ScimEn[:15] # Took only the first 15 ranks
df_initial = pd.merge(ScimEn_initial, Energy_GDP_df, left_on='Country', right_on='Country', how='inner')

# ScimEn = ScimEn[15:]

df = pd.merge(ScimEn, Energy_GDP_df, left_on='Country', right_on='Country', how='inner')

return len(df)-len(df_initial)
```

And it was 147 entries.

I went through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128825/how-to-identify-whats-not-in-the-inner-join-while-merging-3-data-frames) on stack overflow, but the answer wasn't displayed.

Is this the right way to merge 3 data frames but their inner intersection?

P.S. As per the assignment general rule, we are allowed to search or post for solutions on stack over flow:

> This assignment requires more individual learning then the last one
> did - you are encouraged to check out the pandas documentation to find
> functions or methods you might not have used yet, or ask questions on
> Stack Overflow and tag them as pandas and python related. And of
> course, the discussion forums are open for interaction with your peers
> and the course staff.

Comment: One idea, how working if change `ScimEn = ScimEn[15:]` to `ScimEn = ScimEn.iloc[15:]` ?

Comment: If working well it means there is no default index and selecting all rows from label `15` to max label, `iloc` select all rows by position from `15th row` to last row.

Comment: @jezrael the same result

Comment: It gave the same result

Comment: hmm, is possible some duplictes rows? How working if removes them form each dataframe like `energy = energy.drop_duplicates('Country')`

Comment: The same, anyway they didn't say to remove duplicates in question 1 which was the EDA of the whole assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but may be it could help someone else.

```py
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy+Indicators.xls')
    energy = energy[17:244].reset_index(drop=True)
    energy.drop(energy.columns[0:2], axis=1, inplace=True)
    energy.rename(columns={energy.columns[0]:'Country', energy.columns[1]:'Energy Supply', energy.columns[2]:'Energy Supply per Capita', energy.columns[3]:'% Renewable'}, inplace=True)
    energy.replace('...', np.NaN, inplace=True)
    energy['Energy Supply'] = energy['Energy Supply'] * 1000000
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace('\d+','')
    replacement1 = {"Republic of Korea": "South Korea", "United States of America": "United States", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong"}
    energy['Country'].replace(replacement1, inplace=True)
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
    GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', skiprows=4)
    GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name':'Country'}, inplace=True)
    replacement2 = {"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran", "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}
    GDP['Country'].replace(replacement2, inplace=True)
    ScimEn = pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    GDP_last10_years = GDP.drop(GDP.columns[4:-10], axis=1)
    merged_df1 = pd.merge(left=ScimEn, right=GDP_last10_years, how='left', left_on='Country', right_on='Country')
    merged_all_df_big = pd.merge(left=merged_df1, right=energy, how='left', left_on='Country', right_on='Country')
    merged_all_df = merged_all_df_big.head(15)
    remove_cols = ['Country Code', 'Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code']
    merged_all_df.drop(remove_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
    merged_all_df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
    return merged_all_df
```